# git branches following me whenever I create new directories

Tags: git

After running into a few problems trying to push a new project (just one test file) to a new repository on github, I discovered that I've seemed to have made a huge blunder with git in that I have a project and branches following me around whenever I create new directories on my mac.

For example, I create a new directory in the sites folder of my mac

```
cd sites
me$ mkdir mynewdirectory
```

If I do 'git branch' from the sites directory, it shows this

```
* master
  refactor
```

If I recall correctly, this master and refactor branch seems to be from a project i was working on a few weeks go. 
If I cd into mynewdirectory and do 'git branch' I get the same result

```
 git branch
* master
  refactor
```

I then did 'git status' and got a very long list of

```
a) Changes not staged for commit; and 
b) Untracked files
```

These are all obviously unrelated to the new project i want to start, and I'm guessing is part of the reason why I had trouble pushing to a new remote origin.

Is there a way that I can get rid of all this while doing the least amount of harm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have initialized a Git repo in either your home directory (`~`) or else the parent of all the directories you're creating subdirectories in. If you're in a subdirectory of a Git repo, you can get the root directory of the repo using

```
$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

You probably don't want to have your whole home directory and all of your files within be tracked in a Git repo, so I'd recommend moving that directory aside (e.g., `mv ~/.git ~/.git.old` if the repo is in your home directory) temporarily and create more focused repos for each project you want stored in Git. Once you've renamed the old repo, you should no longer have it interfering with your subdirectories and you can use `git init` as normal to create per-project repos.

I said "temporarily" above because, if you *have* committed anything to that repo that you don't want to permanently delete, you probably will want to copy it into a new repo or someplace else so you don't lose it. One way to do that would be to move that old `.git` directory into a new subdirectory from which you can pull out the stuff you want to store elsewhere, and once you've moved everything out you can delete the subdirectory. For example:

```
mkdir old_home_repo
mv ~/.git ~/old_home_repo
cd old_home_repo
git checkout -- .   # this will bring the files that were in the repo back into this directory
# copy files out of this dir, into new places you want to keep them permanently
cd ..
rm -rf old_home_repo
```

Comment: It looks like there is a repo in my home directory. I did  ~/.git
-bash: /Users/me/.git: is a directory.   I then moved it aside 'temporarily' as you suggested, and it worked. But what do you mean when you say 'temporarily'? Is there not a permanent solution?

Answer (score 1):

if u have initiated git in your sites folder then you will get that refactor branch in all the subdirectories.

Comment: I guess I have but I don't want that. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: if u wanna get rid of your refactor branch than u can delete it by,
git branch -D refactor

Comment: should I do the same with master?Is that the only permanent solution?

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I don't have enough reputation points to give your answer an upvote :(